# Swap is filling up and shutting down applications, but most of my RAM is free

Tags: macos, memory, virtual-memory

I have a mac pro with 64 GB of RAM and a 14 GB swap file. I'm running a Jupyter notebook that eats up a lot of memory, so much that the OS is telling me it's out of memory and I need to close applications. When I look at the total memory usage in `htop`, I see that the swap file is indeed full, but I have almost 40 GB of free RAM!

**Why isn't MacOS using the available RAM?**

**How can I stop it from running out of swap when it has a lot of free RAM?**

Comment: Not sure if I should answer here or there.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232011/os-x-swapping-with-free-memory-available

Comment: Can you reboot and gather two sysdoagnose, one immediately after restarting and another after one hour of using jupyter. What swap does that scenario end with. The short nastier is going to be identify the program leaking severely and path or reboot to avoid swap exhaustion.

Comment: @bmike I know which programs are using a lot of swap (it's mainly the jupyter notebooks), I just don't know why they're not using the system's RAM first.

Comment: It’s likely a very oddball bug where it’s leaking memory that’s dereferenced. They sysdiagnose will capture vm regions so the developer can fix it. Apple is unlikely to change the paging algorithm because chrome or jupyter has memory allocation issues.

Comment: @bmike: It's not leaking a significant amount of memory, I'm just analyzing a very large amount of data. The machine has 64 GB of RAM for a reason.

Comment: @bmike: you said apple is unlikely to change the paging algorithm: does that mean that this is how XNU behaves normally?

Comment: @Dan Did you figure this out? Do you still care? If yes to either, please [join the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111308/reopen-swap-is-filling-up-and-shutting-down-applications) and fill us in. I would like to see this question reopened and answered.

Comment: @OldPro I never figured it out. I don't have access to the machine anymore, I moved on to a new job about a year after asking it. I'd still *like* to know the answer, but it's no longer a pressing concern.